# Chrome-extension: Different ways of adding dialog boxes?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've developing a Google chrome extension and I'm wondering what are the different options available to me when adding dialog boxes? I need something which has it's own head and body elements. Basically my Dialogs will be custom stlyed forms with some JQuery. What are the options available to me? I'm already aware of iframes but is there anything else available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome API doesn't provide any help with dialogs. So whatever you can do with a javascript (+jquery +plugins) is what you got, just like on a regular html page.